# Check if region where $\dot{x} > 0$, $\dot{y} > 0$ is positively/negatively invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, set-invariance

I have the following linear system $\dot{x} = -x$ and $\dot{y} = -2y + 2x^3$. I need to characterise the regions where $\dot{x} > 0, \dot{y} > 0$, $\dot{x} < 0, \dot{y} > 0$ and so on.

I am trying to do so for the former region given by $L = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y < x^3, x < 0 \}$. How do I check it's invariance **without** computing the flow explicitly.

Comment: You'll need a bit more insight than just a sign analysis, because for example if you want to ask whether it is possible to leave the region $x<0$ then you need to take into account that $|\dot{x}|$ will decrease as you approach $x=0$, fast enough that you won't hit it.

Comment: @Ian what would you suggest? I've spent a while on this question, should I try to compute the flow? I have drawn nullclines in the plane if that helps

Comment: Well it wouldn't be hard to compute the flow in this context. But in terms of a sign analysis, you look at $(y-x^3)'=-2y+2x^3-3x^2 x' -2y+5x^3$. Now $-2y+2x^3$ is positive but $-2y+5x^3$ could be negative, at least within the region you're looking at. You see why this simple sign check doesn't save the day? It does save the day when $x^3-y$ and $x$ have the *same* sign.

Comment: Typo: it was supposed to be $-2y+2x^3-3x^2x'=-2y+5x^3$.